# How to profile a mysql db?

Tags: mysql, performance, profiling

I'm an mssql veteran who's received a job that involves tuning a mysql db. with mssql it was simply a matter of firing up the db profiler and then crunching up the data it collects. I can't seem to find anything similar for mysql.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the [PROFILER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-profiles.html) in the mysql query tool and profile individual statements.  Also see [Using the New MySQL Query Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) or [How to profile a query in MySQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/10/12/how-to-profile-a-query-in-mysql/).

You can also use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html) to get the query optimization plan, but it only works for SELECT queries.